# Add class to all meta boxes for a custom post type

Tags: php, filters, hooks, variables

I am using an OOP approach to doing all the work in creating the CPT and its meta boxes. For admin styling purposes, I want to do some heavier styling for a specific custom post type. My object method creates the following HTML results:

```
<div id="client_info" class="postbox ">
    <button type="button" class="handlediv" aria-expanded="true"><span class="screen-reader-text">Toggle panel: Client Info</span><span class="toggle-indicator" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    <h2 class='hndle'><span>Client Info</span></h2>
    <div class="inside">
        <label for="client_info_client_first_name">Client First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="custom_meta[client_info_client_first_name]" id="client_info_client_first_name" value="" />
        <label for="client_info_client_last_name">Client Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="custom_meta[client_info_client_last_name]" id="client_info_client_last_name" value="" />
        <label for="client_info_client_age">Client Age</label>
        <input type="number" name="custom_meta[client_info_client_age]" id="client_info_client_age" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is add a custom class to the `<div>` element for each box that is the same so that the `class` attribute would be like: `class="postbox my-class"`

I have tried using `add_filter()` in order to do this but the problem is the only hook I can find relevent is the `postbox_classes_{$page}_{$id}` which I cannot figure out how to make dynamic as I want my object's method to handle registering the filter. I have tried using concatenation with `.` and HereDoc style:

```
function meta_box_add_class( $classes ) {
    array_push( $classes, 'jldc-fitcase-meta' );
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'postbox_classes_custom-post-type_' . $box_id, 'meta_box_add_class' );
add_filter( 'postbox_classes_custom-post-type_{$box_id}', 'meta_box_add_class' );
```

Is there a way to add this hook dynamically as each metabox is created?

Comment: fyi, the `body` tag has classes that let you target specific post type admin screens.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even think to look at that. But I am still curious if it is possible to use hooks like I was originally attempting.

Comment: I actually solved it. I cannot do it directly with the `add_action()` or `add_filter()` statement, but rather I can create a variable and and then do it. Your solution worked by the problem is the CSS would effect every meta box, including the default ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some playing around, I discovered this can actually be accomplished by defining the name of the hook I want to add the filter to via a variable.

So if my `$post_type_name` is `portfolio` and my `$box_id` is `piece_info`, I can make a filter as follows:

```
function add_meta_box_class( $classes ) {
   array_push( $classes, 'custom-class');
   return $classes;
}
$filter_name = 'postbox_classes_' . $post_type_name . '_' . $box_id;
add_filter( $filter_name , 'add_meta_box_class' );
```

This will result in a filter being created using the `postbox_classes_{$page}_{$id}` hook as `postbox_classes_portfolio_piece_info`.